# What is the advantage of using hreflang attribute in <a> tag?

Tags: html

When I use the hreflang attribute I didn't see any different result? So, I want to know what is the advantage of this hreflang attribute?

Comment: href attribute is used to provide the website address which you want to open on your anchor tag click.

Comment: "hreflang" attribute..

Comment: All the `hreflang` attribute does is hint at the human language of the linked URL. Nothing else. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Comment: @YogeshKumarGupta `hreflang` not `href`

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-hreflang

> Hints at the human language of the linked URL. No built-in
> functionality. Allowed values are the same as the global lang
> attribute.

So it indeed does nothing at least visually. It might help screenreaders telling users that the link points to a foreign language page.